# Why the filesystem is closed automatically?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, mapr

I am running and spark job that reads from a kafka queue and writes this data into avro files with spark.
But in the cluster when it is running more or less 50 minutes it get this exception

```
20/01/27 16:21:23 ERROR de.rewe.eem.spark.util.FileBasedShutdown$: Not possible to await termination or timout - exit checkRepeatedlyShutdownAndStop with exception
20/01/27 16:21:23 ERROR org.apache.spark.util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Thread-2
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.checkOpen(MapRFileSystem.java:1660)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:633)
```

The spark configuration and properties is this one

```
SPARK_OPTIONS="\--driver-memory 4G--executor-memory 4G--num-executors 4--executor-cores 4--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=768--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0--conf spark.executor.memory=4g--master yarn--deploy-mode cluster"
```

But the 50 minutes that it is running it is working fine.

Comment: Any reason not to use Kafka Connect to write Avro files?

Comment: This looks like it would be more efficient to handle as a support request.